# error arising in solvepnp ; Assertion error OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

This is done for pose estimation

After performing calibration, the output imgpoints and objpoints are being given as input to the `solvePnP` function as:

```
ret,revc,tvec= cv.solvePnP(temp1,temp2, cameraMatrix, dist)
```

Error which is arising is:

```
error: (-215:Assertion failed) ( (npoints >= 4) || (npoints == 3 && flags == SOLVEPNP_ITERATIVE && useExtrinsicGuess) || (npoints >= 3 && flags == SOLVEPNP_SQPNP) ) && npoints == std::max(ipoints.checkVector(2, CV_32F), ipoints.checkVector(2, CV_64F)) in function 'cv::solvePnPGeneric'
```

adding a code snippet :

```py
objpoints = np.ascontiguousarray(objpoints)

imgpoints = np.ascontiguousarray(imgpoints)

temp1 = np.stack(objpoints,axis=0)

temp2 = np.stack(imgpoints,axis=0)

ret,revc,tvec= cv.solvePnP(temp1,temp2, cameraMatrix, dist)
```

Can someone pls help with this ?

Comment: It says you don't have enough points, and we have no way of knowing the sizes of your points arrays. Also, you've defined `temp2` but not used it. Was that intentional?

Comment: @beaker i have edited the code, it was a mistake, thank you. Also for to having enough points, you mean the objpoints?

Comment: Well, yes, object and image points. If it's not the number of points, it must be the other condition in the assertion that's failing.